# How to in mockito create folder of method call?

Tags: java, testing, directory, mockito, creation

Form docs:

```
   Comparable c=mock(Comparable.class);
    when(c.compareTo(anyInt())).thenReturn(-1);
```

I would like:

```
 File tempDir=new File("test");
   Comparable c=mock(Comparable.class);
    when(c.compareTo(anyInt())).thenReturn(tempDir.mkdir());
```

So will be created real folder (i will use it next private method of class).
Does it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  `File.mkdir()` returns a `boolean` and `Comparable.compareTo(Comparable)` returns an `int`.  So no, that can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incredibly unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  I'm not at all certain why you want to do something like this in the first place.

As I said in my comment, the reason your current example won't compile is because `File.mkdir()` returns a `boolean` and `Comparable.compareTo(Comparable)` returns an `int`.  You can, however, make this compile if you are mocking a method that returns a `boolean`, like so:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("/tmp/111");
    Bar bar = mock(Bar.class);
    when(bar.isTrue()).thenReturn(file.mkdir());
  }

  public static interface Bar {
    public boolean isTrue();
  }
}
```

That said, I seriously doubt this will do what you want.  The line `when(bar.isTrue()).thenReturn(file.mkdir());` *actually invokes* `file.mkdir()`.  So your directory will be created when you create your mock.  In other words, the previous example can (and should) be equivalently written as:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("/tmp/111");
    Bar bar = mock(Bar.class);
    boolean dirMade = file.mkdir();
    when(bar.isTrue()).thenReturn(dirMade);
  }

  public static interface Bar {
    public boolean isTrue();
  }
}
```

Writing it like this would avoid any confusion on when the directory was actually created.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It helps me better understand mocking.